how we can implement power automata when if any file exist in adls we need to send mail abc@outlook.com with attachment
Child Activity:

Check if any files exist in the specified folder of the Azure Data Lake Storage account.
If files are found:

Send an email to ABC Outlook.

Include a subject indicating that files were found in ADLS.
In the email body, provide any necessary information.
Attach the file(s) found in the ADLS folder.




If no files are found, the flow ends without sending any emails


OUT LOOK ACTION WE DONT HAVE ACCESS WE HAVE ACCESS FOR OFFICE 365
